# Load a full menu with active trail

Tags: theming, navigation

I need to load a full menu for navigation in a custom theme with active trail, and can't find any way to do it, but that can't be right.  I can't imagine such an obvious and widespread use-case having no core support, but I've scoured [menu.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/7) and found nothing.  The functions offered range from inadequate (no active trail) to completely unusable (menu is missing children for the CSS dropdowns/submenus outside the active trail, and even empty when needed most, such as on broken links).

I've tried using the following functions in my THEME_preprocess_page hook:

- menu_tree (only renders siblings of the active trail--the navbar can even end up empty)
- menu_tree_page_data (same result)
- menu_tree_all_data (contrary to the documentation--luckily--this method does not return hidden items, but there's no active trail)

So far as I can tell, my only options are to copy and rewrite several functions from menu.inc, or to load two separate menus and apply deep analysis/merging to find and duplicate the active trail from the incomplete menu into the complete one--and this is just as bad because the data structures don't match.  Is there no other way to get a full menu with active trail?

Also, what if I do go with the latter option using menu_tree_all_data?  Will I end up exposing links that aren't properly going through access checks, or have similar issues?  How the heck does Drupal itself load a full menu, like the Navigation menu which doesn't go away while visiting other parts of the site?

I did find another nearly identical [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16872/drupal-7-function-menu-tree-page-data-not-working-correctly) but no one answered it and that was 9 months ago.  This is for a project that's already running well behind schedule due pretty much exclusively to unforseen Drupal-related issues, so any pointers are much appreciated.

EDIT: Whoops...tried to be thorough and missed a major detail :P  I'm on Drupal 7.

Comment: Hi there, please, could you add a Drupal version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I have to say, the menu system that is implemented in Drupal is, in my eyes, **really** dodgy. You'll encounter stuff you simply cannot realize with the core implementation, which you would think is basic use cases.

Depending on which Drupal major you are using, I'd suggest taking a look at the [Menu Settings per Content Type (CTM)](http://drupal.org/project/ctm) when your at **D6**. This module will enable you to setup menu settings per content-type, which contains an option to "expand items by default".

On D7 this feature is built-in, when you create a menu item under `admin/structure/menu` you will find a checkbox `Show as expanded`, which will do the same.

**Edit:**

## Menu block module

I was just thinking about it again, and remembered that [menu_block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block/) module also will help you out in this situation. You can create a block which has a lot more options then al the built-in menu functionalities. Also there is an option: `Expand all children of this tree.`, I think that'll be your ticket out of this problem, and should leave the burdon for your clients to actually manually expand them

Comment: Can "show as expanded" be made to apply by default or triggered in code (in some Drupal-'proper' way)?  Clients will be creating content that they put in the menu so the procedure needs to be kept straightforward without hidden steps.

Comment: It looks like I'll have to write my own "menu_tree_full_data" function based on "menu_tree_page_data."  I'm awarding the answer since the "show as expanded" hint is what finally put me on the right track.

Comment: @HonoredMule, I've edited my original answer. Please take a look at it, I think this will sort out your problems, without the need of hooking PHP up in the core module.

Comment: I'm actually already using menu_block for other things, but because I need to inject the menu into a menu bar area and not a region, this wouldn't work.  It's possible I might have been able to turn the menu bar into a region, but my efforts in that direction went quite badly, screwing up the surrounding header layout.  I now have a solution I'm very happy with, and I'll post it shortly since it's very reusable.

Comment: Turning the menu bar into a region would have been pretty wonky anyway, since no block would ever be able to go there without the layout going pear-shaped.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add my experience to the lot. I had similar issues using Drupal menu. The solution I used is:

- Set all menu items with children to "Expanded". This as to be done manually: `Structure > Menus > List links`, edit links which has children, check the `Show as expanded` checkbox.
- Use `menu_tree_page_data` function (example: `$menu_tree = menu_tree_page_data('main-menu')`) to get the menu, with all its children AND with active trail.
- Create a renderable array using `menu_tree_output` function (example: `$renderable_array = menu_tree_output($menu_tree)`) to prepare the menu for rendering.
- Use the renderable array as content for my custom block, but you could call `drupal_render($renderable_array)` to get the rendered HTML representing the menu.

Comment: This does it perfectly - no additional modules or templating. One small edit use `main-menu` in code rather than `main_menu`

Comment: Thanks Scott Lawrence, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own "menu_tree_full_data" function that builds the menu, still using all the appropriate cache facilities, etc.  Also take note any Drupal Core developers around: this is how you write a function that *isn't* incomprehensibly nested 9 blocks deep.

```
function menu_tree_full_data($menu_name) {
    $tree = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

    // Check if the active trail has been overridden for this menu tree.
    $active_path = menu_tree_get_path($menu_name);

    // Generate a cache ID(cid) specific for this page
    $item = menu_get_item($active_path);
    $cid = "links:$menu_name:full:{$item['href']}:{$GLOBALS['language']->language}";

    // Did we already build this menu during this request?
    if(isset($tree[$cid]))
        return $tree[$cid];

    // If the static variable doesn't have the data, check {cache_menu}.
    $cache = cache_get($cid, 'cache_menu');
    if($cache && isset($cache->data)) {
        $tree_params = $cache->data;
        if(isset($tree_params))
            return $tree[$cid] = menu_build_tree($menu_name, $tree_params);
    }

    $tree_params = array(
        'min_depth' => 1,
        'max_depth' => null,
    );
    // Parent mlids; used both as key and value to ensure uniqueness.
    // We always want all the top-level links with plid == 0.
    $active_trail = array(0 => 0);

    // Find a menu link corresponding to the current path. If $active_path
    // is NULL, let menu_link_get_preferred() determine the path.
    $active_link = menu_link_get_preferred($active_path, $menu_name);
    // The active link may only be taken into account to build the
    // active trail, if it resides in the requested menu. Otherwise,
    // we'd needlessly re-run _menu_build_tree() queries for every menu
    // on every page.
    if(@$active_link['menu_name'] == $menu_name) {
        // Use all the coordinates, except the last one because there
        // can be no child beyond the last column.
        for($i = 1; $i < MENU_MAX_DEPTH; $i++) {
            if($active_link['p' . $i])
                $active_trail[$active_link['p' . $i]] = $active_link['p' . $i];
        }
    }

    $parents = $active_trail;
    do {
        $result = db_select('menu_links', NULL, array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            ->fields('menu_links', array('mlid'))
            ->condition('menu_name', $menu_name)
            //->condition('expanded', 1)
            ->condition('has_children', 1)
            ->condition('plid', $parents, 'IN')
            ->condition('mlid', $parents, 'NOT IN')
            ->execute();
        $num_rows = FALSE;
        foreach($result as $item) {
            $parents[$item['mlid']] = $item['mlid'];
            $num_rows = TRUE;
        }
    } while($num_rows);
    $tree_params['expanded'] = $parents;
    $tree_params['active_trail'] = $active_trail;

    // Cache the tree building parameters using the page-specific cid.
    cache_set($cid, $tree_params, 'cache_menu');

    // Build the tree using the parameters; the resulting tree will be cached by _menu_build_tree().
    return $tree[$cid] = menu_build_tree($menu_name, $tree_params);
}
```

Aside from changing the cache key, commenting out the `expanded` condition, dropping the no-longer-relevant `$max_depth` and `$only_active_trail` arguments, and the branching on `$item['access']` (whether the user can access current page), this is logically equivalent to [`menu_tree_page_data`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/7).  4 of the extra 5 levels of nested code blocks could be just as easily removed from the original function as well.

Now I can finally just load the menu I need as I need it with no mess or fuss, like so:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

    if(@$vars['main_menu']) {
        $menu = variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu');
        $vars['main_menu'] = menu_tree_output(menu_tree_full_data($menu));
    }
}
```

And use it in my theme like so:

```
<?= render($main_menu); ?>
```

Or something like so (this is how a lot of other themes seem to handle it, though it just makes a mess for me):

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
    <nav id="primary-menu" role="navigation">
        <?php print theme('links__system_primary_menu', array(
            'links' => $main_menu,
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
            )
        )); ?>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Of course you still have to define or include the menu_tree_full_data function somewhere as well.  For me, it goes in a "Shorthand" module I maintain with various simplified object-oriented API wrappers, where it'll also get turned into a method in SH_Menu class and get loaded on demand with shorthand_load_menu();  (Note you've gotta switch `__FUNCTION__` for `'menu_tree_full_data'` if you do something similar, or the caching won't work correctly.)